# Auto Signin with Active Directory Account in c# ASP.Net Website

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

We have a website which can be used as intranet for Staffs and internet for outside people.   All our staffs accounts are in Active Directory. So, when the internal staffs browse the URL (For eg. http://app.abc.com), they should be automatically signed in by using their AD accounts.

However, for external users, they have to use their username and password. I could do this part easily just by looking up the database and make authentication.

I would like to know how I could auto sign in the AD users into the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the Windows authentication provider to use Windows authentication (which is the AD authentication).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9.aspx

However, what you're talking about is mixed-mode authentication...  That's a bit more tricky.  But it's covered here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx and here http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050203.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Authenticate(string userName, string passwd)
        {
            //Domain .
            string domain = "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME";
            string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + userName;
            //Path of Active Directory Entry e.g. path="LDAP://DC=onecity,DC=corp,DC=fabrikam,DC=com"; 
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, passwd);

            try
            {
                //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                object obj = entry.NativeObject;

                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
                _path = result.Path;
                _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                PageLogger.AddToLogError("AUTH_ERROR", ex);
                return false;

            }

            return true;
        }

        private  string GetGroups()
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
            search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
            StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
                string dn;
                int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

                for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount; propertyCounter++)
                {
                    dn = (string)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];
                    equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                    commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                    if (-1 == equalsIndex)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                    groupNames.Append("|");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. " + ex.Message);
            }
            return groupNames.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code. Simply dumping code into SO is just crude. What is _path for example?

Comment: @Fandango68 Sure thing, also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor